# Displacing Vertices in the Vertex shader

Tags: opengl, 3d, directx, vertex-shader, procedural-generation

My code creates a grid of lots of vertices and then displaces them by a random noise value in height in the vertex shader. Moving around using

```
glTranslated(-camera.x, -camera.y, -camera.z);
```

works fine, but that would mean you could go until the edge of the grid.

I thought about sending the camera position to the shader, and letting the whole displacement get offset by it. Hence the final vertex shader code:

```
uniform vec3 camera_position;
varying vec4 position;

void main()
{
    vec3 tmp;
    tmp = gl_Vertex.xyz;
    tmp -= camera_position;
    gl_Vertex.y = snoise(tmp.xz / NOISE_FREQUENCY) * NOISE_SCALING;
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
    position = gl_Position;
}
```

EDIT: I fixed a flaw, the vertices themselves should not get horizontally displaced.

For some reason though, when I run this and change camera position, the screen flickers but nothing moves. Vertices are displaced by the noise value correctly, and coloring and everything works, but the displacement doesn't move.

For reference, here is the git repository: https://github.com/Orpheon/Synthworld

What am I doing wrong?

PS: "Flickering" is wrong. It's as if with some positions it doesn't draw anything, and others it draws the normal scene from position 0, so if I move without stopping it flickers. I can stop at a spot where it stays black though, or at one where it stays normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this bug by using glUniform3fv:

main.c exterp:

```
// Sync the camera position variable
GLint camera_pos_ptr;
float f[] = {camera.x, camera.y, camera.z};
camera_pos_ptr = glGetUniformLocation(shader_program, "camera_position");
glUniform3fv(camera_pos_ptr, 1, f);

// draw the display list
glCallList(grid);
```

Vertex shader:

```
uniform vec3 camera_position;
varying vec4 position;

void main()
{
    vec4 newpos;
    newpos = gl_Vertex;
    newpos.y = (snoise( (newpos.xz + camera_position.xz) / NOISE_FREQUENCY ) * NOISE_SCALING) - camera_position.y;
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * newpos;
    position = gl_Position;
}
```

If someone wants to see the complete code, here is the git repository again: https://github.com/Orpheon/Synthworld

Comment: I'll give you the bounty if you also *explain* the bug and the fix.

Comment: Thing is, I don't even completely understand the bug myself. I changed command. I used to use a command that directly passes the floats, and did some mistake there. The fix, for me, was to switch to a command that just passed a pointer to an array (glUniform3fv instead of glUniform3f). This simply worked. So yeah, sorry.

Answer (score 5):

```
gl_Position = ftransform();
```

That's what you're doing wrong. `ftransform` does not implicitly take `gl_Vertex` as a parameter. It simply does exactly what it's supposed to: perform transformation of the vertex position exactly as though this were the fixed-function pipeline. So it uses the value that `gl_Vertex` had *initially*.

You need to do proper transformations on this:

```
gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
```

Comment: Did that, didn't fix the issue though.

Comment: @Orpheon: To be honest, I'm assuming that `gl_Vertex.xyz -= camera_position;` is something meaningful. I have no idea why you would subtract the model-space vertex position by the camera position, but you could somehow be working directly in camera space, so I can't say without more information.

Comment: Sorry. The camera_position is standard 3D space coordinates, not camera space as far as I can discern. I am still a newbie to OpenGL, and yeah, I'm on shaky ground when it comes to those different spaces.

Comment: @Orpheon: There are no "standard 3D space coordinates."

Comment: The same coordinate system you use to give vertex positions in opengl itself.